# Remove spaces from JS code using PHP

Tags: php

I have following generated JS code:

```
    var companies = [
      {
        name:   'foo bar',
        points: [
          {
            latitude: 123,
            longitude: 456
          }
        ]
      } ,              {
        name:   'foo  bar',
        points: [
          {
            latitude: 123,
            longitude: 456
          }
        ]
      } ,              {
        name:   'foo   bar',
        points: [
          {
            latitude: 123,
            longitude: 456
          }
        ]
      } ,              {
        name:   'foo    bar',
        points: [
          {
            latitude: 123,
            longitude: 456
          }
        ]
      }           ];
```

Yes, it's ugly - with extra indent in every line, etc.. Since it's going to be just rendered I would like to remove whitespaces from it using PHP. Expected output should be:

```
var companies=[{name:'foo bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]},{name:'foo  bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]},{name:'foo   bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]},{name:'foo    bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]}];
```

What is the most efficient way to remove whitespaces from JS code ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're actually building JSON by PHP printing it line by line, _not_ by using `json_encode()`?

Comment: @TimPost It's generated in loop with Twig. It doesn't contain all data stored in objects - just a small part.

Comment: @hsz Try this => `preg_replace('/((?<=\[|\{|\]|\}|\,|\:)[\s]+)|(\s+(?=\}))/', '', $str)`

Comment: @RahilWazir Why don't you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @hsz Could you show other possible output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the previous answers, this looks like the regex you need:

```
((?<=\=|\,|\:|\]|\[|\{|\})\s+)|(\s+(?=\=|\,|\:|\]|\[|\{|\}))|(^\s+)
```

To use in php:

```
preg_replace('/((?<=\=|\,|\:|\]|\[|\{|\})\s+)|(\s+(?=\=|\,|\:|\]|\[|\{|\}))|(^\s+)/', '', $str);
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=\=|\,|\:|\]|\[|\{|\})\s+)
```

match one or more spaces \s+ following {}[],:= characters

```
(\s+(?=\=|\,|\:|\]|\[|\{|\})
```

match one or more spaces \s+ preceding {}[],:= characters

```
(^\s+)
```

match starting and ending spaces ^\s+

replace it all with nothingness

see it in action:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/5eS

Answer (score 0):

if it is always json string you can use 
`$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: It's a JavaScript with JSON and other JS synax.

Answer (score -1):

It's all too hacky and you would need to test it to more scenarios.
Update:

```
<?php
         $str = "var companies = [
                  {
                    name:   'foo bar',
                    points: [
                      {
                        latitude: 123,
                        longitude: 456
                      }
                    ]
                  } //...
            ];";

            echo preg_replace(
              array(
                '#\]\s+#' , '#\[\s+#' , '#\{\s+#', '#\}\s+#','#\s+\]#' , '#\s+\[#' , '#\s+\{#', '#\s+\}#' , '#\,\s+#' , '#\:\s+#','#\s+\,#' , '#\s+\:#'),
              array(
                ']' , '[' , '{', '}' ,']' , '[' , '{', '}' , ','  , ':',','  , ':'), $str);
```

Comment: Yup just tested. Works fine.

Comment: @noc2spam It returns `string 'var companies = [              {                name:   'foo bar',                points: [                  {...`

Comment: See my edit now @RahilWazir . It's a bit ugly but works

Comment: @noc2spam It removes now whitespaces from my `foo    bar` string which is invalid behaviour.

Comment: @hsz check again. I used preg_replace this time. It's all too hacky at this moment. Test and see if it works.

Comment: @noc2spam This still removes spaces between `foo    bar`

Comment: @RahilWazir Here's what I got with the last updated code `var companies =[{name:'foo bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]},{name:'foo  bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]},{name:'foo   bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]},{name:'foo    bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]}];`

Comment: @noc2spam But this is what i got `var companies =[{name:'foo bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]},{name:'foo bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]},{name:'foo bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]},{name:'foo bar',points:[{latitude:123,longitude:456}]}];` Spaces removed from `foo bar` :(